# Unexpected JUnit Behavior

Tags: java, junit

I am working with a Java Web Application that has a lot of unit tests. We run the unit tests within Eclipse. I am going through the tests and refactoring some of them. I have seen a few tests that are written like this (I'll boil it down to the assertions, my literal examples actually are variables in the tests)

```
assertEquals(new Integer(7), new Long(7));
```

This test passes!, and I don't understand why, since the types are different. After seeing this behavior, I created a simple Java project in Eclipse and wrote basically the same unit test

```
assertEquals(new Integer(7), new Long(7);
```

and it Failed as I expected. I don't need any help, I was just curious how the test passes in one environment and fails (as it should) in another.

Comment: It will be much easier to help you if you include actual code.

Comment: Are you sure that they're both `java.lang.Integer`s?  If not, perhaps a custom class could override the equals method.... a long shot, no doubt, but it is a _possible_ explanation.

Comment: We'd be grasping at straws here unless you can provide the fully qualified names of `Integer` and `Long`.  I'm agreeing with @EdwinBuck in that this is likely something overriding one of those classes, but I'm not sure what, nor am I sure why.

Comment: Another long shot (but one that I really don't think is happening) is that in some way one can be binding to one value (perhaps by autoboxing) and the other is getting eventually cast to an int.  Meanwhile, you did notice that you're missing a parenthesis in the second unit test you posted, right?

Comment: I agree, it would be nice to see the real tests, especially when it comes to `import`s and version; for example, which version on JUnit are you using? Is it the same for both the original test and your pet demonstration? Out of context, since you are refactoring, get rid of `new Integer` (or `Long`, `Double`, etc) and use `valueof` instead, there's a problem with caching.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the equals method for java.lang.Long it says:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Long) {
        return value == ((Long)obj).longValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

So `new Long(7).equals(new Integer(7))` should be false, because Integer instanceof Long is false. This test program confirms that:

```
public class Stuff {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("int equals long : " + new Integer(7).equals(new Long(7)));
        System.out.println("long equals int : " + new Long(7).equals(new Integer(7)));
    }
}
```

which prints out

```
int equals long : false
long equals int : false
```

I'm guessing the web application test that came up with the opposite result used an add-on like [ComparableAssert](http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/ComparableAssert.html), which has this signature

```
public static void assertEquals(java.lang.Comparable expected,
                                 java.lang.Comparable actual)
```

It would be easy to mistake for the other, especially if the test uses static imports. Longs and Integers are comparable to each other (`new Long(7).compareTo(new Integer(7))` evaluates to 0) so this assert would succeed.